# Randf in correlation to other field QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, random

I'm looking for solution that will allow me to create random values with correlation to other field.
For example:

```
Field_a | Field_b (that will contain random values)   
1       | 0.001  
2       | 0.005  
3       | 0.008
```

That correlation doesn’t need to be high, I don’t want totally random values. In other words, when `Field_a` values are increasing, so does `Field_b`.
Also, both fields **may** have different value ranges, *for example* in `Field_a` values vary between 1 to 10 and in `Field_b` between 0.1 to 0.5.

Comment: Normally `randf(0, "Field_a")`-like expression returns random value based on `Field_a`. What kind of randomness or correlation do you mean?

Comment: Why, for example, `Field_b = Field_a/1000` doesn't meet your need. Actually fussy thing for me here is "*when `Field_a` values are increasing, so does `Field_b`*". `0.001, 0.005, 0.008` values are reasonable for `1, 2, 3`. But what if `Field_a` was `1,3,2,5,10,6`?. /// I don't know if getting the previous/next attribute value is possible in Field Calculator. If it is not, you eventually will need Python script, I guess. By PyQGIS, a suitable solution can be found.

Comment: Dividing values from one field isn’t the option. Let’s say that one field contain values of daily precipitation and the second of soil humidity. Both are related, but not directly. My goal is to add some random values of humidity that will increase along with precipitation. Of course it’s just a random set of data for training and it’s just showing main idea.